# Denoting row vectors and matrix inverses using tensor notation

Tags: tensors

At 3:13 of [this video lecture](https://youtu.be/W3tRrHOTHx8?t=190) by Pavel Grinfeld, he expression the linear algebra equation:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^T A x - x^T  b$$

When he expands out the expression in terms of tensor notation,

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^i x^j A_{ij}  - x^i b_i$$

I don't understand how he did this conversion in these following parts:

- From my knowledge of tensors, matrices entries are written as $A_{j}^{i}$ where 'j' denotes row and 'i' denotes column, So how did he write as $ A_{ij}$ here?
- Why was he able to write both $ x $ and $ x^T$ in the form of $ x^k$?
- Also, continuing from the first bullet point, if metric tensor can be represented as a matric, why do we write it as $ g_{ij}$ instead of $ g_{i}^{j}$